# Does Discrete Math require Calculus?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

So I'm transferring to UC Berkeley and they require Discrete Math or 1 other math class for me to declare my Psychology major.

So it is highly recommended to take Calculus for maturity before entering it, and I suck at math but I need this class to declare. I'm not even yet at Trig and have no time to build into Calc.

I have some Algebra 2 knowledge and was wondering if Discrete Math is gonna kick me in the gluteus maximus without the recommended Calc?  Like if I would still be able to grasp its concepts without that math "maturity". I really need Discrete Math but will not have time to meet the recommended requirement.

I was hoping to take it and get tutored and take advantage of study time, and read ahead, if it helps.

Comment: Not usually, but calc might help a little bit. Discrete Math has more to do with proofs than derivatives, integration, and series, which are the generally covered topics of Calculus. As long as you have a good understanding of basic Algebra, you will probably be ok. UC Berkeley might require it anyway... I'm not sure, I don't go there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  UC Berkeley highly recommends taking Calculus but does not require it!

Comment: That said, if you're going into Psychology, you *should* prioritize learning calculus, as it forms a foundation for statistics, and sadly, many practitioners blindly apply statistical methods with no care given to the underlying math.,

Answer (score 1):

Most discrete math does not require calculus at all. Usually you can take them concurrently but in all reality you do not need calculus for most discrete math topics.